# Field extension of abstract variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> Let $X$ be a variety (separated, integral, finite type) over a field $k$.
>   Let $K$ be a Galois extension of $k$. 
>   Then, is it true that $X_K = X \times_k \text{Spec}\,K$ is also a variety?

I think this is enough to observe locally. So, we may assume $X= \text{Spec}\,A$ where $A$ is an integral domain and $k$-algebra. I tried to show that $A \otimes_{k} K$ is also integral domain. But i don't know how to do this. 
Can you help me??

Comment: What happens to $A=\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)$ when you extend scalars from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q(i)$?

Comment: Have you ever heard people throw around the words "geometrically integral"? There's a good reason!